# Powershell: Pipe output of Get-ADUser into Set-MsolUserLicense

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm newish to Powershell and I'm stuck trying to figure this one out. We're migrating to Office 365, and it's been a headache, not necessarily from Microsoft or our Provider, but we've had a lot of 'fun' getting this to work in our favor.

I have a CSV of users that I have to remove their license in O365 from one-product and re-license them for another product. I'm trying to do this as two 'one-liners' and I'm lost. Here's what I have so far:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\convert.csv" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_.user | select UserPrincipalName | Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "mycorp:ENTERPRISEDESKLESS"}
```

The CSV has a header of 'user' and a few user records as just their account names. If I check the command up to the output of the Select function, everything is working correctly, it's the piping of that output into Set-MsolUserLicense that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a way to test it right now but it should work like this

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\convert.csv" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_.user | Set-MsolUserLicense -RemoveLicenses "mycorp:ENTERPRISEDESKLESS"}
```

Per help information for Set-MsolUserLicense

```
-UserPrincipalName <string>
    The user ID of the user to update.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    named
    Default value                
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Parameter UserPrincipalName is accepting input from pipeline and ByPropertyName, so since Get-ADUser will provide property of that name for you when you pipe it to Set-MsolUserLicense it should be able to automatically use correct value.

Comment: That did seem to work. I keep seeing an error about an invalid license, but it seems to be making the changes regardless. Thanks!